# laravel eloquent belongsTo fetches wrong data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have two tables. One contains the user and the other contains meetings. 
Each meeting belongsTo exact one User.

Meetings

```
class Meeting extends Model { 
protected $table = 'meetings';
protected $primaryKey = 'owner_id';

/**
 * A meeting belongs to exact one User
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
}}
```

User

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $table = 'users';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

/**
 * One User can have many Meetings
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function meetings(){

    return $this->hasMany(Meeting::class, 'owner_id');
}
```

I fetch the data with

```
$meetings = Meeting::with('user')->get();
```

But somehow i don't get the related user. It just iterates over all users in the database and breaks if no more user is given.

What the heck am I doing wrong? O.o

Comment: IMHO I dont understand how can a user have many meetings via owner_id field if owner_id is also a primary key? And the inverse should be belongsTo(User::class, 'owner_id');

Answer (score 1):

Let try to change it:

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
}
```

To

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'owner_id', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `Meeting` model there are 2 strange things:

`protected $primaryKey = 'owner_id';`

Why is that? Shouldn't it be `id` here?

Second thing:

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
}
```

probably here instead of `id` you should user `owner_id`.

So to sum up it seems you set wrong keys for primary key and for relationships and probably that's the reason relationship doesn't work as it should.

Comment: The primary key of the Meetings table is owner_id and the primary key of the user table is id. So it should be correct or am I wrong?